# The classical correspondence in the harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, ground-state

In the harmonic oscillator, the ground state is the one with minimum uncertainty (and also other squeezed states that satisfy the 'equal to' in the Heisenberg inequality). This should mean that these states are closest to classical correspondence. This seems intuitive.

But if we were to consider some higher energy states, then a look at the probability density for these states suggests that the repeated oscillations can be averaged out to give the classical picture, as the plot below suggests.
[image: probability density for higher n]

So isn't there some inconsistency in the way in which we are looking for classical-quantum correspondence through this averaging method?

Thank you!